Alexa skill account linking is unsuccessful with error : Unable to link the skill at this time.Please try again later
I have a problem that has been confused me for several days.
My smart home skill is in development status, when attempting to link account,get the error: Unable to link the skill at this time.Please try again later.
The problem is：
When I turning off the "Send Alexa Events" permissions from the Alexa developer console and then test account linking. It works, and my lambda function received Discovery directive.
When I turning on the "Send Alexa Events" permissions from the Alexa developer console and then test account linking. It did not work, and my lambda function received nothing.
I have checked as per the documentation: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/account-linking/troubleshooting-account-linking.html
I am sure that my oauth server can receive the request and respond with the correct authorization code and accesstoken And my other skills also use the same oauth server and work fine.
I'm confused.
Has anyone encountered the same problem?
